# Unable to display data in multi select drop down Angular 6

Tags: angular, dropdown, multi-select

I am using this multiselect library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown in Angular v6.

I am trying to display my list in multiSelect, but the drop down is showing me "**No data available**"

If I hardcode my response as follows then the list is populating fine. I cannot understand what is wrong. **Why is my response not working, but if I hardcode it then works fine?**

```
this.members = [
  {
    "item_id": "user1@gmail.com",
    "item_text": " User 1"
  },
  {
    "item_id": "user2@gmail.com",
    "item_text": " User 2"
  }]
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select Member Names'" [data]="members"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedMembers" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**TS**

```
export class IndividualDashboardComponent implements OnInit {


  selectedMembers: Array<any> = [];
  getIndividualMemberResponse: any;
  statusCode: number;
  members = [];
  dropdownSettings = {};
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private toastMessageService: NotificationService, private http: HttpService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMembers();

    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 4,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };

  }
  getMembers() {
    let teamName: String = "All";
    let urlString: any = environment.ALL_TEAM_MEMBERS + teamName;
    this.http.getRequest(urlString, null, null)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        (<Array<String>>data).forEach(member => {
          this.members.push({ item_id: member, item_text: member });
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.members))
      },
        (error: Response) => {
          this.getIndividualMemberResponse = error;
          this.statusCode = this.getIndividualMemberResponse.status;
          this.toastMessageService.errorMessageToast(this.statusCode);
        });
  }


  onItemSelect(item: any) {
    if (this.selectedMembers.length === 0) {
      $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
  onItemDeSelect(item: any) {
    if (this.selectedMembers.length === 0) {
      $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDITED**

Changed my method as follow but did not work either.

```
  getMembers() {
    let urlString: any = environment.ALL_TEAM_MEMBERS + 'All';
    this.http.getRequest(urlString, null, null)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.members = 
         (<Array<String>>data).map(member => ({ item_id: member, item_text: member }));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.members))
      });
  }
```

Comment: Have you verified you're getting the data you expect in your `getMembers()` method? Also it looks like you're assigning the entire object to your properties. `{ item_id: member, item_text: member }`. Should that be something like `{ item_id: member.id, item_text: member.text }`?

Comment: @Narm I am simply getting  response as [user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com,user3@gmail.com]  so I am picking member and mapping on item_id: member (<Array<String>>data).forEach(member => {

Comment: Is your `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.members))` returning correctly? Could you provide us the ouput of that?

Comment: @penleychan This the stringify response. I have just rename data and reduced limit from 38 to 3 

[
  {
    "item_id": "user@group.com",
    "item_text": " user  first name"
  },
  {
    "item_id": "user@group.com",
    "item_text": " user  first name"
  },
  {
   "item_id": "user@group.com",
    "item_text": " user  first name"
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The main issue is the fact that the select component expects a value of type `{item_id:number, item_text:string}[]` for the `data` property, but you are mapping the `data` in the subscribe callback in a wrong way.

Notice that you are pushing objects into the `members` array whose properties `item_id` and `item_text` are the elements of the `data` array being iterated in the subscribe callback.

Instead of:

```
this.members.push({ item_id: member, item_text: member });
```

You should have

```
this.members.push({ item_id: member.item_id, item_text: member.item_text });
```

You could easily avoid this kind of issues by being more *explicit* about the types of your instance members. For example:

```
interface SelectItem {
  item_id: number;
  item_text: string;
}

export class IndividualDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
   members: SelectItem[] = [];
   ...

   getMembers(){
     ...
     this.http.getRequest(urlString, null, null)
      .subscribe((data: SelectItem[]) => this.members = data);
     ...
   }
}
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Most likely your issue is related to the fact that you *mutate* the `members` array. The select component [has onPush change detection](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/blob/master/src/ng-multiselect-dropdown/src/multiselect.component.ts#L26), which re ensures my guess.

Try *setting* the `members` array with a new value instead of mutating it. You can do this by refactoring your code to use `map` instead of `forEach` inside of the subscribe callback, as follows:

```
this.members = data
```

Comment: I did something like this but not working. :(    getMembers() {
    let urlString: any = environment.ALL_TEAM_MEMBERS + 'All';
    this.http.getRequest(urlString, null, null)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.members = 
         (<Array<String>>data).map(member => ({ item_id: member, item_text: member }));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.members))
      });
  }

Comment: @Mishi Could you please add that modification to your original question? that way it will be easier to read and follow. Simply edit and add the modified version of `getMembers` at the end

Comment: Saw the issue, updating

Comment: It is displaying values now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Mishi added some further remarks to the answer. You just shot yourself in the foot by not using types in the declarations of your class members ;(

Comment: Just for my knowledge can you please explain me why your solution worked. I mean by using.map

Comment: Thanks alot for letting me know :)

Comment: @Mishi For the sake of simplicity, and not overload you with information, lets say that components with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` wont pick up changes in the state of an object, eg. an array, once its already _bounded_ through an `@Input` property. Because of this, its better to "signalize" angular by passing a new array to the input property. You might want to read https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/